# Value Event Listener Returns Null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

### My Datastructure

### [image: Datastructure]

I am trying to get the `TeacherId` from the teacher with the same email of the currently logged in teacher from my database.Then store it to a string variable then later pass it to an adapter class for querying again. but everytime I try to retrieve it using `ValueEventListener` it returns `null`.

### My Code

```
public class SchedList extends AppCompatActivity {

    //member vars. ui objects
    public ListView SubSchedListView;
    public TextView schedList;
    public TextView tIDTextView;

    //data vars
    private String email;
    private String teacherid;
    private ArrayList<DataSnapshot> snapshot;

    //classes
    private TeacherAccount ta;
    private subjSchedAdapter mAdapter;

    //
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    //listener

    private String x;
    private String y;
    private String z;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sched_list);

        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("teacheraccount").child("TeacherId");

        //ui objects
        SubSchedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SubSchedListView);
        schedList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.schedTextView);
        tIDTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tIDTextView);

        //data vars
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        snapshot = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Query query = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("Email").equalTo(intent.getStringExtra("email"));

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ta = dataSnapshot.getValue(TeacherAccount.class);
                x = ta.getTeacherId(); //the part where it says it returns null
                y = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals("TeacherId")) {
                    z = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                }

                Log.d("WHICH_HAS", x + y + z);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        // Setting the adapter
        Log.d("WHICH_HAS", x + y + z);

        //mAdapter = new subjSchedAdapter(this, mDatabaseReference,teacherid);

        SubSchedListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        mAdapter.cleanup();
    }
}
```

At which part is there something wrong ? should the `valueListener` be in the `Onstart` ? `OnCreate` ? or on its own function ? if so, at which part do I call the function ? at what other parts did I do wrong at ?

How do you pass a string data to a base adapter class ?

### My Base Adapter class

```
public class subjSchedAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Activity mActivity;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private String mTeacherId;
private ArrayList<DataSnapshot> mSnapshotList;
private Query query;
private Context mContext;
// child event listener

private ChildEventListener mListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        mSnapshotList.add(dataSnapshot);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        mSnapshotList.add(dataSnapshot);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};


//constructor

public subjSchedAdapter(Activity activity, DatabaseReference ref, String id){

    mActivity = activity;
    //mTeacherId = subjteacherid;
    mDatabaseReference = ref.child("subjects");

    //this is where id = the teacherId I retrieved
    query = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("teacherid").equalTo(id).limitToFirst(1);

    query.addChildEventListener(mListener);

    mSnapshotList = new ArrayList<>();

}

//view holder

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView subjectCodeAndName;
    TextView time;
    TextView sectionName;
    TextView teacherId;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mSnapshotList.size();
}

@Override
public SubjectScheds getItem(int position) {

    DataSnapshot snapshot = mSnapshotList.get(position);

    return snapshot.getValue(SubjectScheds.class);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subject_sched_list, parent, false);

        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.subjectCodeAndName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subjectCodeAndName);
        holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        holder.sectionName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sectionName);
        holder.teacherId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.teacherid);
        holder.params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.subjectCodeAndName.getLayoutParams();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    final SubjectScheds subjectsched = getItem(position);
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    String subjcodeandname = subjectsched.getSubjectCode() + " - " + subjectsched.getSubjectName();
    String time = "time : " + subjectsched.getTime();
    String sectionName = "section : " + subjectsched.getSectionname();
    String teacherId = "teacher : " + subjectsched.getTeacherid();

    holder.subjectCodeAndName.setText(subjcodeandname);
    holder.time.setText(time);
    holder.sectionName.setText(sectionName);
    holder.teacherId.setText(teacherId);

    return convertView;
}

public void cleanup(){

    mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mListener);

}
```

}

### The part in the code where I set the adapter

### Method Call

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot finalSnap :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ta = finalSnap.getValue(TeacherAccount.class);
                x = ta.getTeacherId(); //the part where it says it returns null

                tIDTextView.setText(x);

                Display(x);

            }
        }
```

### Method

```
private void Display(String x){

    mAdapter = new subjSchedAdapter(this,mDatabaseReference,x);
    SubSchedListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have got the wrong database reference if you want to OrderbyChiled by Email then you want to get the reference to the parent of that specific field.

As per your case you need to find reference to teacher account as per follow:

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("teacheraccount");
```